# Key error when accessing pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, keyerror

I get an error when trying to access a single element in a pandas dataframe this way `test_df["LABEL"][0]`. Here is a code snippet on how I am loading the data:

```
print "reading test set"
test_set = pd.read_csv(data_path+"small_test_products.txt", header=0, delimiter="|")

print "shape of the test set", test_set.shape 
test_df = pd.DataFrame(test_set)
lengthOfTestSet = len(test_df["LABEL"])
print test_df["LABEL"][0]
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
  File "code.py", line 80, in <module>
    print test_df["LABEL"][0]
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 521, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 3562, in get_value
    loc = self.get_loc(k)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 3619, in get_loc
    return super(Float64Index, self).get_loc(key, method=method)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 1572, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(_values_from_object(key))
   File "pandas/index.pyx", line 134, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3824)
   File "pandas/index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3704)
   File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 541, in pandas.hashtable.Float64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:9914)
   File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 547, in pandas.hashtable.Float64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:9852)
 KeyError: 0.0
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry what are you attempting here? If you want to access the first row you can do `test_df['LABEL'].iloc[0]`, it's likely that `0` is not in your index, please post the first few rows of your raw input data

Comment: @EdChum yes that's what I am trying to do. But surprisingly, the indexing train_df["LABEL"][0] worked for me, but didn't work for test_df

Comment: BTW, you don't need the `test_df = pd.DataFrame(test_set)`, as `read_csv` already gives you a DataFrame

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Like EdChum said 0 is probably not in your index.

Try: `df.iloc[0]` or `df['label'].iloc[0]`, which is integer based location.

To reset the index if you are having trouble with that: `df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Check out panda's [indexing doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) for more information on it

Comment: This works. I used data.iloc[index] to read value at index from series.

Answer (score 1):

In the case in the OP, the variable name `test_df` suggests that it was created by splitting a dataframe into train and test sets, so it's very likely that `test_df` didn't have `index=0`. You can check it by

```py
0 in test_df.index
```

and if it return False then there isn't `index=0`.

Nevertheless, to access the first row, you can use `test_df.iloc` or `test_df.take()` (similar to `numpy.take`) or even `loc`:

```py
test_df.take([0])
test_df.iloc[0]
test_df.loc[test_df.index[0]]
```

For a scalar value, you can even use `iat`:

```py
test_df["LABEL"].iat[0]
```

If the index is not important and you want to reset it to a range index, then as [Seth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31164304/19123103) suggests, reset the index; just make sure to assign the result back (so that the change is permanent).

```py
test_df = test_df.reset_index()            # the old index becomes a column in the dataframe
test_df = test_df.reset_index(drop=True)   # the old index is thrown away
```

You may also get a key error for columns if the dataframe doesn't have a column with a specific name. A common culprit is a leading/trailing white space, e.g. `'LABEL '` instead of `'LABEL'`. The following should return True for you to select LABEL column.

```py
'LABEL' in test_df.columns
```

If the above returns False, try

```py
test_df.columns = test_df.columns.str.strip()
```

and try selecting via `test_df['LABEL']` again.